# HTML page not loading after postback call

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, client-server, postback

I try to implement postback call in my web application.
When I do post call to the server the server side function fired, make some logic and generate HTML response code and send back to the page.The problem that HTML response from server not loading in the page.

Here is more detailed example:

Here is the page that make post call to the server:

[image]

And here JavaScript code of the page:

@inherits System.Web.WebPages.WebPage

```
<h2>GmailOAuthCallback</h2>

<li><a href="/OauthCallBack/GmailOAuthCallback/">Get Contacts</a></li>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $ = jQuery.noConflict()

    $(document).ready(function () {
    alert("yeah...")
        $.post("/OauthCallBack/GmailOAuthCallback",
               { "code": $.urlParam("code") },   //code(in paranthes) - is name of parameter to search
                    function (resp) {
                        // alert(resp)
                            });
    })

    $.urlParam = function (name) {
        var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
        if (results == null) {
            return null;
        }
        else {
            return results[1] || 0;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Here is the function that catch post call and sends respons(the response is html page called **Index**) back to the page:

```
  public class OauthCallBackController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult GmailOAuthCallback(string code)
        {
            if (Session["contacts"] == null)
                Session["contacts"] = GmailServiceWorkflow.GetContacts(code); ;

            ViewBag.contacts = Session["contacts"];
            return View("Index");
        }
    }
```

But when I get the response from the server the new content not desplayed I see the old content.
I checked response in firebug console the response is success.

And here how it's looks like:
[image]

Any idea why do I see the old page content after the client get response(i.e. why response not loaded to the page)?

Comment: are you trying to redirect here or pull down partial view code to be inserted into your view?  according to the documentation on .post this is used for pulling down data or partial views, not full views

Comment: @Matt I try to redirect

Comment: I would recommend using window.location instead.  that will do a page redirect instead of an ajax post.

Comment: ok,I will try it now .